# Take the folder name and put in the variable

Tags: powershell, directory

How can I take the name of the current folder and put into a variable in powerShell?

Thanks.

Comment: It's already a variable: `$PWD`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get the current working directory with

```
pwd
```

(pwd is an alias for Get-Location)

if you then select this as an object you can get the path

```
pwd | Select-Object | %{$_.ProviderPath}
```

you can split this

```
pwd | Select-Object | %{$_.ProviderPath.Split("\")}
```

Then take the last - which is you folder name

```
pwd | Select-Object | %{$_.ProviderPath.Split("\")[-1]}
```

to assign to a variable

```
$folderName = pwd | Select-Object | %{$_.ProviderPath.Split("\")[-1]}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I can't upvote yet. :)

Comment: No need for Select-Object or foreach. $location = (Get-Location).Path | Split-Path -Leaf

Comment: @Dave One better, `$location = $pwd | Split-Path -Leaf` since `$pwd` already is the "Present Working Directory" path

Answer (score 2):

to return your current location use `Get-Location`

Comment: This will return the full path, not only the current folder name.

Comment: Correct. I assumed that's what OP wanted. Sorry if I was wrong.